# How to check if an email was read in Exchange 2010 using powershell?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

We are searching through inboxes for Exchange 2010 and trying to find out is a specific email was read by the specified user/mailbox.

We can leverage powershell for the search, unsure of how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You could use Exchange Web Services.  [You will need to download the API.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42951)  This will require the user running the script to have have authority to access the mailbox in question and you know the subject of email you're looking for.

```
Import-Module -Name "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"

$exchService = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2010)
$exchService.AutodiscoverUrl("email@yourdomain.com",{$true})

$Mailbox = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Mailbox("email@yourdomain.com")
$Inbox = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($exchservice,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox)

$MessageView = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(100) #Find Max 100 Items

$SerachFilter1 = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessageSchema]::Subject,"Test Subject")
$SerachFilter2 = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessageSchema]::IsRead, $false)
$SearchFilterCollection = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+SearchFilterCollection([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.LogicalOperator]::And)
$SearchFilterCollection.Add($SerachFilter1)
$SearchFilterCollection.Add($SerachFilter2)

If($Messages.TotalCount > 0){

    #Do something....
}
```